# Join command in Bash

Tags: bash, join, terminal

I community. I've got a problem with bash terminal. There are two files that I need to merge and I want to use delimiter ; in join command, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thanks!

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -t; tasks.txt procowner.txt > answ.txt
```

upd. bash message

```
join: option requires an argument -- t
usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2
zsh: command not found: tasks.txt
```

Comment: I use this command: join -1 2 -2 2 -t; tasks.txt procowner.txt > answ.txt
join: option requires an argument -- t
usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2
zsh: command not found: tasks.txt

Comment: You tagged your question with `bash` but your error message says you're using `zsh` instead. Please correct your tag or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` is treated as a command terminator by `bash`.  This in turn means `bash` sees two separate commands:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -t

# and

tasks.txt procowner.txt > answ.txt
```

The first one generates a syntax error for the `join` command; the second one generates an error stating `tasks.txt` is not a valid command.

The simple fix is to quote the `;`, eg:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 -t';' tasks.txt procowner.txt > answ.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately the simple fix didn't solve the problem. It's empty in answ.txt